# How can I change toolbar runtime in MFC Visual C++ 2010

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have two toolbars desgined of equal size and equal number of buttons.
Now based on some condition in code I want to change toolbars run time.
My prject is MDI application built in Visual C++2010 MFC.
Please help as early as possible.My application uses CMFCToolbar

Comment: Please make your question more precise: Using the new MFC-Next classes (CMFCToolbar) or the traditional CToolbar class?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using CMFCToolbar you can just call: CMFCToolbar::GetCommandButtons (a static function). You get an Object array of all buttons in your system and you can change them accordingly (SetToolTip, SetImage ...)

The problem is that CMFCToolbar is variable and buttons can be inserted and dragged around. SO you need the access via GetCommandButons.

---

If you are using the classical CToolBar class the easiest way is just to add the button, so it always exists in the toolbar and in the bitmap.

If the button should not be visible at startup you just call DeleteButton with the index you receive from CommandToIndex.

To change the button you can just use SetButtonInfo.

If you need the button again, just call InsertButton, with the index where you want to have this button.You may save the previous index and used bitmap index before you delete it.

Comment: Is  there  no  way  to change  toolbar  in  MFC?

Comment: Actually  I  am  converting  application  in  Multilanguage.Unfortunately  I  cannnot  maintain  separate  Rc  file

Comment: I just added a new section to my answer.

Comment: I   have  same  ids  for  buttons  as  I  am  creating  multilanguage  application.So cannot have  two  sets  of  buttons  with same ids

Comment: And where is the problem? Surely you can have more than 1 button with the same Id in your application. Also your question has been answered. I showed you how to retrieve the button and how to change it.